# How to programatically select a checkbox in a MS Word 2007 document or template?

Tags: ms-word

I've created a document and I am able to use Content Controls to populate the document, but now there is a requirement to select a checkbox on the form. Is there a "Checkbox Content Control" or must I use the older ActiveX checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not for Content Controls in Word 2007. It does exist as a Content Control in Word 2010 though. In either program, you can use an ActiveX checkbox, but it's usage is kind of wonky.

Comment: Thanks Otaku, I did see that in the Developer toolbar, but how would I access it in the code to set it?  It looks like a Legacy control and does go to XML, but not accessible from Content Control toolkit.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I've got the solution...wait for Office 2010. :)

Seriously though, I ended up converting to PDF and used iTextsharp.